# Parsing Text File in R

Tags: r, parsing

I have a text file I would like to parse in R with the following structure listed below.
The delimiters of the fields are "START" and "END".

START
apple
banana
banana
END
START
orange
apple
watermelon
END
...

How do I parse this in R to get the 
content between the delimiter.
Can I use an XML library to parse this in R?

Comment: Also the data appear in one column going down.  Each word is a row.
So row1 = "END", row2 = "START", row3 = "apple"...

Comment: Could you please put the above comment in the original post?  I added something to my answer, based on your comment. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
x <- "START apple banana banana END START orange apple watermelon END ..."

library(gsubfn)
strapplyc(x, "START (.*?) END", simplify = c)
```

giving:

```
[1] "apple banana banana"     "orange apple watermelon"
```

Comment: What if the data is in one column vector though, instead of a row vector?

Comment: Please provide an example of the input you are referring to in reproducible form.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `strsplit`:

```
> x <- "START apple banana banana END START orange apple watermelon END"
> z <- unlist(strsplit(x, "((START)|(END))|(END START)"))
> z[nzchar(z)]
[1] " apple banana banana "     " orange apple watermelon "
```

You could also use `gsub` if you don't need the string separated into substrings:

```
> gsub("START|END", "", x)
[1] " apple banana banana   orange apple watermelon "
```

If you want all the remaining words separated, a combination of both will work:

```
> unlist(strsplit(gsub("START | END", "", x), " "))
[1] "apple"      "banana"     "banana" 
[4] "orange"     "apple"      "watermelon"
```

---

EDIT/ADD:

From your comment, it sounds like your data is a single-column data frame.  If that's the case, you could do something like this:

```
## set up the data
> d <- data.frame(words = unlist(strsplit(x, " ")))
> d$words <- as.character(d$words)
> d
        words
1       START
2       apple
3      banana
4      banana
5         END
6       START
7      orange
8       apple
9  watermelon
10        END

## remove unwanted words by subsetting
> d[-with(d, which(words == "START" | words == "END")), ]
[1] "apple"      "banana"     "banana"     "orange"     "apple"      "watermelon"
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it just one line? If you wish to only use base R, try

```
line <- readLines("filename")[[1]]
data <- strsplit(line, " END START ")[[1]]
data[c(1, length(data))] <- gsub("^START | END$", "",  data[c(1, length(data))])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach:

```
x <- "START apple banana banana END START orange apple watermelon END"

library(qdap)
genXtract(x, "START\\s", "\\sEND")

##     "apple banana banana" "orange apple watermelon"
```